# Why kotlin coroutines don't require thread context switching

Tags: java, android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Many resources indicate that the kotlin coroutines are lightweight because they do not require switching the context of threads.

As you know, coroutines work on a thread pool, then why can't these threads have context switching? If there are more threads involved than processor cores?

Please help me figure this out

Answer (score 1):

If we run two tasks, each of them in a separate thread, then whenever we have to switch execution from one task to the other, we have to switch CPU to execute another thread, which is a heavy operation. If we run two tasks using coroutines, we can switch between them by reusing the same thread and only switching its coroutine. This is much lighter. Most probably this is what resources you mentioned meant.

Another, and maybe even more important difference is in memory consumption. We can easily launch even a million of coroutines and they will be just fine. Trying to do the same with threads will most probably results in an out-of-memory error.

Comment: in Dispatchers.IO pool of 64 threads, if you create a million coroutines, then 64 threads will be busy? and still have to switch the context of the stream?

Comment: I'm not sure if I got your question right, but if you use `Dispatchers.IO` with default config, then only 64 coroutines can be run in parallel, including waiting in a blocking call. All other coroutines are enqueued.

Comment: so after all, if there are fewer threads than cores in the processor, then the thread context switches. 64 threads is that a lot and big performance gaps?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow you. Context switches are required if there are more threads than CPU cores. If there are fewer of them then at least hypothetically, we never need to switch the context. `Dispatchers.IO` is kind of special case - we can't avoid blocking the thread while doing the blocking I/O, so we allow to run more threads than optimal. But the context switch isn't that relevant in that case, because the delay of the I/O itself is probably several levels of magnitude bigger than the delay of the context switch.

Comment: sorry, my question is, can context switching still happen? (almost all articles about coroutines say this does not happen). And if a context switch occurs (a million coroutines are created, for example for an IO stream) - does it not load the system?

Comment: Context switches occur naturally, also while using coroutines. It is very hard to avoid them, but we shouldn't be too obsessed about them.